# Getting StackOverFlow Exception in ASP.NET C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

So I have created an HTTP Handler (.ashx.cs) in c# and I am constantly getting a System.StackOverflowException, it doesn't seem to tell me where the problem lies. I understand that with some google search it tells me theirs too many recursive calls, but I cannot find out exactly where I am doing this.

Here is my Handler Page;

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            int userID;
            userID = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]);

            string streamHash;
            streamHash = HttpContext.Current.Session["Stream"].ToString();

            int streamID;
            streamID = GetStreamID(streamHash);

            List<StreamUserMenues> listMenu = new List<StreamUserMenues>();

            using (DBEntities contextDB = new DBEntities())
            {
                var userStreamMenuList = contextDB.StreamMembers.ToList();

                foreach (var listItem in userStreamMenuList)
                {
                    StreamUserMenues streamUserMenu = new StreamUserMenues();
                    streamUserMenu.Id = listItem.StreamMembersID;
                    streamUserMenu.streamId = listItem.FKStreamID;
                    streamUserMenu.UserId = listItem.FKUserID;
                    streamUserMenu.UserNameText = listItem.FKUserID.ToString();
                    //streamUserMenu.isApproved = (bool) listItem.isUserApproved;
                    //streamUserMenu.isUserGuest = (bool) listItem.isGuest;
                    //streamUserMenu.isOnline = (bool) listItem.isUserOnline;
                    listMenu.Add(streamUserMenu);
                }
            }

            List<StreamUserMenues> menuTree = GetMenuTree(listMenu, streamID);
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(menuTree));
        }
```

On the handler page, this is where I am getting an error;

```
private List<StreamUserMenues> GetMenuTree(List<StreamUserMenues> list, int streamID)
        {

            return list.Where(x => x.streamId == streamID).Select(x => new StreamUserMenues()
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                streamId = x.streamId,
                UserId = x.UserId,
                UserNameText = x.UserId.ToString(),
                //isApproved = x.isApproved,
                //isUserGuest = x.isUserGuest,
                //isOnline = x.isOnline,
                List = GetMenuTree(list, x.streamId)

            }).ToList();
```

This is where I am calling the Handler;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'StreamUserMenuHandler.ashx',
                method: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    buildMenu($('#menu'), data);
                    $('#menu').menu();
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err.statusText);
                }
            });

            function buildMenu(parent, items) {
                $.each(items, function () {
                    //var li = $("<li><a href=" + window.location.href + "?StreamHash=" + this.URL + ">" + this.MenuText + "</a></li>");
                    //var myLink = '<li><a href="' + window.location.href + "'";
                    //myLink += '?StreamHash=';
                    var li = $("<li>" + this.UserNameText + "</li>");


                    if (!this.Active) {
                        li.addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                    }

                    li.appendTo(parent);

                    if (this.List && this.List.length > 0) {
                        var ul = $("<ul></ul>");
                        ul.appendTo(li);
                        buildMenu(ul, this.List);
                    }
                });

            }


        });
    </script>
```

The Exception that I am getting is;

```
System.StackOverflowException
  HResult=0x800703E9
  Message=Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.
```

Comment: how many rows are there in `contextDB.StreamMembers`? if it's too many, use `paging`, like `contextDB.StreamMembers.Skip(pageNumber*pageSize).Take(pageSize)`

Comment: @Dongdong, there are a total of 6 rows in contextDB.StreamMembers :/ . I dont think thats too big

Comment: The recursive call to GetMenuTree is causing the exception. The recursion condition is not correct

Comment: `GetMenuTree` cannot stop by your logic.

Comment: Presumably the recursive call should be something like `GetMenuTree(x.SomeSubList, streamId)`.  Or at the very least you shouldn't be calling it with the exact same list.

Comment: Sorry I dont seem to understand.

Comment: @MilanConhye `GetMenuTree` iterates a list and on each iteration it calls `GetMenuTree` with the same list so it iterates the list and on each iteration it calls `GetMenuTree`..... and so on and so on into infinity.

Comment: Any hints how I can fix this issue @juharr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say:

1. the `StreamMembers` contains 5 rows which have same `streamId`, the id is `1001`.

then:

2. `List<StreamUserMenues> menuTree = GetMenuTree(listMenu, "1001")`;
3. `list.Where(x => x.streamId == 1001)` will the get 5 rows.
4. `List = GetMenuTree(list, "1001")` will give the 5 rows again and again, endless....

I believe your `StreamMember.FKStreamID` is a FK which points to `StreamMember.StreamMembersID`, so your logic should be:

```
private List<StreamUserMenues> GetMenuTree(List<StreamUserMenues> list, int streamID)
{
    return list.Where(x => x.streamId == streamID).Select(x => new StreamUserMenues() 
    {
        .....
          List = GetMenuTree(list, x.Id) //be aware: it's x.Id, not x.streamId
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! = ). I knew it could be something simple

Comment: NP. but I would suggest you rename `FKStreamID` and `SteamId` to `ParentId`, and `List` to `Children`, which will have you less mistakes in further debugging.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a recursive function, you have always to be sure to have a base case, which it doesn't see to be the case.

It seems to me that you are just passing the same list and id over and over again, which will cause your program to throw the error.

Comment: Technically the base case here is an empty list that will result in no recursive call.  However the real issue is that the original list is being passed instead of something that would eventually lead to an empty list.